# How to save a Matplotlib graph

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I tried saving my matplotlib graph using

```
plt.savefig('graph.pdf')
```

Yet, when I open the file it is blank. How can I save my graph properly?

I am doing something similar to this [Left Ventricle Bull eye (AHA) matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25784646/left-ventricle-bull-eye-aha-matplotlib)

Comment: Maybe show the rest of your code?

Comment: Works for me.  It might help to show which version of matplotlib you are using, and show `plt.rcParams['backend']`.  Also, which operating system are you running this on?

Comment: @bernie check the edits.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I'm running this on a mac

Comment: `plt.savefig('graph.pdf')` is a documented command, which is working without problem. If you have a problem with it, you need to provide a [mcve] of the issue together with a complete problem description.

Answer (score -1):

Try saving in with ".png" extension:

```
plt.savefig('graph.png')
```

Also, if you have plt.show() that it will end the instance and there will be nothing to save. Put saving before plt.show().

Comment: Are you using Jupyter Notebooks? Then do you put the code to save the graph in the same cell as where you plot the graph?

Comment: Also, if you have plt.show() that it will end the instance and there will be nothing to save. Put saving before plt.show().

Comment: Saving before plt.show()  solved the problem. thank you